# D3D11_REQ_CONSTANT_BUFFER_ELEMENT_COUNT actual definition?

Tags: directx-11

Does the D3D11_REQ_CONSTANT_BUFFER_ELEMENT_COUNT limit on constant buffer means it has to be max D3D11_REQ_CONSTANT_BUFFER_ELEMENT_COUNT bytes size, or is it really a number of element? i.e. max bytes size would be D3D11_REQ_CONSTANT_BUFFER_ELEMENT_COUNT * element size (16 bytes) ?

Comment: From the name, i think it's number of elements, not bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a maximum size on the number of four component floating point vectors that can be addressed in a single constant buffer. It is not a number of arbitrary data elements that can be stored, as that depends on how many components of the vectors the element takes up. In answer to your question, yes, `D3D11_REQ_CONSTANT_BUFFER_ELEMENT_COUNT*(4*sizeof(float))` is the maximum number of bytes that can be used for any one constant buffer. Why you would need this information is not quite clear, but here it is regardless.

NOTE:

This is the case in DirectX 10 and 11, but not in 11.1. In DirectX 11.1, constant buffers can be created that are larger than the limit (64K), but cannot be updated all at once. They must be updated in chunks of 64K using *SetConstantBuffers for the first 4096 elements or *SetConstantBuffers1 for any set of up to 4096 elements.

Comment: I need this because I want to know when I try to allocate a constant buffer that is too large. I just wanted to be sure it really is an element count, and not a byte count. I guess Microsoft didn't mess that one. :P